# QGIS Server loads only one .qgs project file

Tags: wms, windows, qgis-server, apache

I installed **QGIS Server** in WinXP via OSGeo4W and runs great. But the problem is, it loads only one .qgs project file. I restarted Apache but it is same. I use QGIS 1.9 default WMS client. I noticed that QGIS Server only load one project file and **it looks to the filename first char**... For example if i generated  project files named as **abc.qgs** and **xyz.qgs** it loads abc.qgs. Do you have any idea ???

Comment: I have done some tests and it seams QGIS Server consider only the first project he founds.

Answer (score 1):

How do you access the two projects? It doesn't seem that you're accessing them by putting the url for each project as you should.

You can see [here](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial) that

> Similar to UMN mapserver, the map parameter can be used to specify the path to the QGIS projectfile. If not specified, QGIS searches for .qgs files in the directory where the server executable is located.

Example: http://myserver.com/cgi/qgis_mapserv.fcgi?MAP=/home/user/mymap.qgs&...

Check apache error log for problems but my guess is that if you put in the correct urls to the projects everything should be ok.